# convert generator object to list

Tags: list, python-2.7

Trying to convert this generator into a list of list. Got an error: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable. Using python 2.7

```
perm = itertools.permutations(range(1, 4))
```

Comment: All you need to do is `list(perm)`. You need to be more specific about the error you faced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to convert to a `list` of `list`s (instead of generator of `tuple`s), `map` can do this easily:

```
perms = map(list, itertools.permutations(range(1,4)))
```

If a `list` of `tuple`s is all you need, it's even easier:

```
perms = list(itertools.permutations(range(1,4)))
```

Just don't do it for permutations on a larger set of inputs, or you'll exhaust memory pretty quickly.